# Probability of having a complete random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

What is the probability that a random graph [`G(n,p)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph) with n nodes and probability p = c some constant value is complete?

By complete I mean that every pair of nodes is connected by an edge. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) for further details.

Comment: Hint: how many edges does the complete graph on $n$ nodes have?

Comment: @David - (n choose 2) if it is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your notation, I'm assuming that $p$ is the probability for the existence of an edge between any two nodes. Then you can think of the generation of a random graph as a series of ${n\choose2}$ Bernoulli trials, one for each possible edge, with probability $p$ of success in each trial. The probability that they are all successes, and so resulting in a complete graph, is $p^{n\choose2}$.